# Plotar grafos - R

Tags: r, plot

Alguém sabe uma biblioteca, em R, para plotar grafos com grandes quantidades de vértices ( próximo à 3.000 vértices)?

Comment: Testou o `plot.ly`?

Comment: http://igraph.org/r/

Comment: Testei e funcionou! Vlw!